# How to exactly match the previous group including case insensitivity?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I think this is something that simply does not exist. But I know that *some* of the functionality exists in other regex engines, I'm hoping they maybe something similar to this.

```
pattern = r"""
    ([a-zA-Z])    # Match a single letter and capture it as group1
    .*?           # random matches in between
    \1            # Match whatever capture group1 matched
"""
```

Now this matches AA, bb and so on. So far so good in python. 
Now some language (idk if python regex engine does) allows

```
pattern = r"""
    ([a-zA-Z])    # Match a single letter and capture it as group1
    .*?           # random matches in between
    \U1           # Match group1 in upper case
"""
```

There are couple of "function" like this that allows you to somewhat manipulate the prev capture groups but they are very limited from what I read at [some regex website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html)

Now my question is that, is it possible to write our own "functions" for regex to use somewhat like

```
@re.register_function('X')
def between_x(group):
    return f'X{group}X'
```

and then

```
pattern = r"""
    ([a-zA-Z]{2})    # Match a single letter and capture it as group1
    .*?              # random matches in between
    (\X1)            # Match if the previous group is inbetween Xes.
"""
# For example, AArandomletterXAAX would match and group1 would be AA
# and second group would be XAAX
```

Doesn't need to be the `re` module, I'm open to any other regex engines.

---

As an example the pattern should match

```
string: "hello...HELLO"
```

and not match

```
string: "hello...hello"
```

given that our function is

```
def f(group):
    return group.upper()
```

Comment: @Emma tried my best, but I'm not sure how can I give more examples as this is more about a general feature and not a specific question about a pattern.

Comment: Note that the link you included specifies replacement patterns, which might not be available in the search pattern even if the regex engine implement them (not that it matters in your case since Python's doesn't implement them)

Comment: The `\U` is imho a perl [replacement feature](https://regex101.com/r/blsgXG/1) that also works in some text editors. In some regex flavors you can use [conditonals](https://regex101.com/r/blsgXG/2) else you'd need to use [alternation](https://regex101.com/r/blsgXG/3). Any callback functions are program-side not regex features I'd think :p

Comment: I think you should let the regex match both `hello...HELLO` and `hello...hello` then have python check the case. The regex could leverage use of the inline case-insensitive flag, e.g. `([A-Za-z]+).*?(?i)\1` (although in this case it makes more sense to run the whole regex with the case-insensitive flag)

Comment: You can't register any functions like this. In Perl, you may use inline code blocks for that, but that is not possible in Python. In PCRE, there are callouts that might work, but again, that won't work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite interesting, and I'm sure it has a great solution, if I understand it correctly.

---

We can maybe start with an expression with three sub-expressions:

```
([a-z]+)(.+?)((?=.+[A-Z].+)(?i:\1))
```

Here we are having a starting lowercase word:

```
([a-z]+)
```

followed by anything in between:

```
 (.+?)
```

and here is the group we should be working on, if we really wish to solve this problem:

```
((?=.+[A-Z].+)(?i:\1))
```

We are backrefereing with an `i` flag, which is working fine.

Now, it would most likely pass all case insensitive letters from the first capturing group and fails the entirely lowercase third group, which I'm hoping that's what might be desired here.

> If not, this group `((?=.+[A-Z].+)` is actually what we might want to focus on
> to pass our desired third group and fail the undesireds.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/1yVeI9/1/)

Comment: Upvoted because it partially solves the one one example I have, and partially manipulates the previous capturing group with already existing regex functionality. What I was hoping for, or what I'm searching for is a way to add arbitrary manipulations to the regex groups to extend what regex can offer by default.